Show that the sequence $(y_i)$ takes each strictly positive integer value exactly once.
Let $(y_i)$ with $i$ an integer strictly positive, a sequence defined by $y_1=1$ and, for k>0 :
$y_{2k} =
 \begin{cases}
 2y_k & \text{if $k$ is even}\\
 2y_k+1 & \text{if $k$ is odd}
 \end{cases}$
$y_{2k+1} =
 \begin{cases}
 2y_k & \text{if $k$ is odd}\\
 2y_k+1 & \text{si $k$ is even}
 \end{cases}$
After testing some values ​​I got this, with $p$ is odd :
$y_{2p}= 2y_p+1$
$y_{2p+1}= 2y_p$
$y_{2(p+1)}= 2y_{p+1}$
$y_{2(p+1)+1}= 2y_{p+1}+1$
Then :
$y_{2+4n}= 2y_{2n+1}+1$
$y_{3+4n}= 2y_{2n+1}$
$y_{4+4n}= 2y_{2n+2}$
$y_{5+4n}= 2y_{2n+2}+1$
But, I don't know how to continue
Help me please.

Check https://oeis.org/A003188

Is it possible to delete a tag ?

First, I would calculate some values starting at $1$
$$\begin {array} \ n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15\\
y_n&1&3&2&6&7&5&4&12&13&15&14&10&11&9&8 \end {array}$$
I note that in each range $[2^n,2^{n+1}-1]$ the $y_n$ values are a permutation of the $n$ values.  Can you justify that the pattern continues?

Thank you, I will try to show that
